# Cuenta atrás en página

Tags: javascript

Llevo unos días haciendo una página para una boda en la que hay una cuenta atrás  (que quiero que sea el 22 septiembre 2018). La cuestión es que  no he conseguido hacer que funcione la cuenta atrás de ninguna manera posible.

El código es este:

```
<script>
var d = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 200 * 120 * 120 * 2000);

// default example
simplyCountdown('.simply-countdown-one', {
    year: d.getFullYear(),
    month: d.getMonth() + 1,
    day: d.getDate()
});

//jQuery example
$('#simply-countdown-losange').simplyCountdown({
    year: d.getFullYear(),
    month: d.getMonth() + 1,
    day: d.getDate(),
    enableUtc: false
});
```

Y el js

```
(function (exports) {
    'use strict';

    var // functions
        extend,
        createElements,
        createCountdownElt,
        simplyCountdown;

    /**
     * Function that merge user parameters with defaults one.
     * @param out
     * @returns {*|{}}
     */
    extend = function (out) {
        var i,
            obj,
            key;
        out = out || {};

        for (i = 1; i < arguments.length; i += 1) {
            obj = arguments[i];

            if (obj) {
                for (key in obj) {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                            extend(out[key], obj[key]);
                        } else {
                            out[key] = obj[key];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return out;
    };

    /**
     * Function that create a countdown section
     * @param countdown
     * @param parameters
     * @param typeClass
     * @returns {{full: (*|Element), amount: (*|Element), word: (*|Element)}}
     */
    createCountdownElt = function (countdown, parameters, typeClass) {
        var innerSectionTag,
            sectionTag,
            amountTag,
            wordTag;

        sectionTag = document.createElement('div');
        amountTag = document.createElement('span');
        wordTag = document.createElement('span');
        innerSectionTag = document.createElement('div');

        innerSectionTag.appendChild(amountTag);
        innerSectionTag.appendChild(wordTag);
        sectionTag.appendChild(innerSectionTag);

        sectionTag.classList.add(parameters.sectionClass);
        sectionTag.classList.add(typeClass);
        amountTag.classList.add(parameters.amountClass);
        wordTag.classList.add(parameters.wordClass);

        countdown.appendChild(sectionTag);

        return {
            full: sectionTag,
            amount: amountTag,
            word: wordTag
        };
    };

    /**
     * Function that create full countdown DOM elements calling createCountdownElt
     * @param parameters
     * @param countdown
     * @returns {{days: (*|Element), hours: (*|Element), minutes: (*|Element), seconds: (*|Element)}}
     */
    createElements = function (parameters, countdown) {
        var spanTag;

        if (!parameters.inline) {
            return {
                days: createCountdownElt(countdown, parameters, 'simply-days-section'),
                hours: createCountdownElt(countdown, parameters, 'simply-hours-section'),
                minutes: createCountdownElt(countdown, parameters, 'simply-minutes-section'),
                seconds: createCountdownElt(countdown, parameters, 'simply-seconds-section')
            };
        }

        spanTag = document.createElement('span');
        spanTag.classList.add(parameters.inlineClass);
        return spanTag;
    };

    /**
     * simplyCountdown, create and display the coundtown.
     * @param elt
     * @param args (parameters)
     */
    simplyCountdown = function (elt, args) {
        var parameters = extend({
                year: 2015,
                month: 6,
                day: 18,
                hours: 0,
                minutes: 0,
                seconds: 0,
                words: {
                    days: 'day',
                    hours: 'hour',
                    minutes: 'minute',
                    seconds: 'second',
                    pluralLetter: 's'
                },
                plural: true,
                inline: false,
                enableUtc: true,
                onEnd: function () {
                    return;
                },
                refresh: 1000,
                inlineClass: 'simply-countdown-inline',
                sectionClass: 'simply-section',
                amountClass: 'simply-amount',
                wordClass: 'simply-word',
                zeroPad: false
            }, args),
            interval,
            targetDate,
            targetTmpDate,
            now,
            nowUtc,
            secondsLeft,
            days,
            hours,
            minutes,
            seconds,
            cd = document.querySelectorAll(elt);

        targetTmpDate = new Date(
            parameters.year,
            parameters.month - 1,
            parameters.day,
            parameters.hours,
            parameters.minutes,
            parameters.seconds
        );

        if (parameters.enableUtc) {
            targetDate = new Date(
                targetTmpDate.getUTCFullYear(),
                targetTmpDate.getUTCMonth(),
                targetTmpDate.getUTCDate(),
                targetTmpDate.getUTCHours(),
                targetTmpDate.getUTCMinutes(),
                targetTmpDate.getUTCSeconds()
            );
        } else {
            targetDate = targetTmpDate;
        }

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(cd, function (countdown) {
            var fullCountDown = createElements(parameters, countdown),
                refresh;

            refresh = function () {
                var dayWord,
                    hourWord,
                    minuteWord,
                    secondWord;

                now = new Date();
                if (parameters.enableUtc) {
                    nowUtc = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(),
                        now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds());
                    secondsLeft = (targetDate - nowUtc.getTime()) / 1000;

                } else {
                    secondsLeft = (targetDate - now.getTime()) / 1000;
                }

                if (secondsLeft > 0) {
                    days = parseInt(secondsLeft / 86400, 10);
                    secondsLeft = secondsLeft % 86400;

                    hours = parseInt(secondsLeft / 3600, 10);
                    secondsLeft = secondsLeft % 3600;

                    minutes = parseInt(secondsLeft / 60, 10);
                    seconds = parseInt(secondsLeft % 60, 10);
                } else {
                    days = 0;
                    hours = 0;
                    minutes = 0;
                    seconds = 0;
                    window.clearInterval(interval);
                    parameters.onEnd();
                }

                if (parameters.plural) {
                    dayWord = days > 1
                        ? parameters.words.days + parameters.words.pluralLetter
                        : parameters.words.days;

                    hourWord = hours > 1
                        ? parameters.words.hours + parameters.words.pluralLetter
                        : parameters.words.hours;

                    minuteWord = minutes > 1
                        ? parameters.words.minutes + parameters.words.pluralLetter
                        : parameters.words.minutes;

                    secondWord = seconds > 1
                        ? parameters.words.seconds + parameters.words.pluralLetter
                        : parameters.words.seconds;

                } else {
                    dayWord = parameters.words.days;
                    hourWord = parameters.words.hours;
                    minuteWord = parameters.words.minutes;
                    secondWord = parameters.words.seconds;
                }

                /* display an inline countdown into a span tag */
                if (parameters.inline) {
                    countdown.innerHTML =
                        days + ' ' + dayWord + ', ' +
                        hours + ' ' + hourWord + ', ' +
                        minutes + ' ' + minuteWord + ', ' +
                        seconds + ' ' + secondWord + '.';

                } else {
                    fullCountDown.days.amount.textContent = (parameters.zeroPad && days.toString().length < 2 ? '0' : '') + days;
                    fullCountDown.days.word.textContent = dayWord;

                    fullCountDown.hours.amount.textContent = (parameters.zeroPad && hours.toString().length < 2 ? '0' : '') + hours;
                    fullCountDown.hours.word.textContent = hourWord;

                    fullCountDown.minutes.amount.textContent = (parameters.zeroPad && minutes.toString().length < 2 ? '0' : '') + minutes;
                    fullCountDown.minutes.word.textContent = minuteWord;

                    fullCountDown.seconds.amount.textContent = (parameters.zeroPad && seconds.toString().length < 2 ? '0' : '') + seconds;
                    fullCountDown.seconds.word.textContent = secondWord;
                }
            };

            // Refresh immediately to prevent a Flash of Unstyled Content
            refresh();
            interval = window.setInterval(refresh, parameters.refresh);
        });
    };

    exports.simplyCountdown = simplyCountdown;
}(window));

/*global $, jQuery, simplyCountdown*/
if (window.jQuery) {
    (function ($, simplyCountdown) {
        'use strict';

        function simplyCountdownify(el, options) {
            simplyCountdown(el, options);
        }

        $.fn.simplyCountdown = function (options) {
            return simplyCountdownify(this.selector, options);
        };
    }(jQuery, simplyCountdown));
}
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Que fecha almacenas en d????

Answer (score 1):

No es un problema muy complejo, la solución, es utilizar un `setInterval` para ir decrementando la fecha a la que se pretende y comparándola con la fecha actual

**Ejemplo**

```js
//Asignas la fecha a una variable
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 22, 2018 00:00:00").getTime();

// Intervalo de 1 segundo
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Obtenemos la fecha actual
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Chequeamos la distancia entre la fecha que pretendemos y la de hoy
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Calculamos días, horas, minutosy segundos
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Mostramos el resultado en el <p> con id 'demo'
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // Si terminó el tiempo, cambiamos el texto
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Llego la boda!!!";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
p{
font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias he podido utlizar parte del código  para rehacer lo que necesitaba, aunque realmente me quedo con la duda de si el otro funcionaba.

Comment: @Marta posiblemente sí, pero si existe una solución simple al problema, no busques la complicada!